# Use form to create multiple fields in Access 2010

Tags: forms, ms-access

So I have a form I have Vendors fill out when they want to ship to us. It's an excel form that I then import into Access so I can run reports. Sometimes when they send the form back it's in a format in which I have to manually enter the data into our database.

The form looks like this: 
[image]

The middle section is just for example purposes so it's a rectangle with text in it.

So everything seemed simple enough until I got to the middle section. See in my excel form I have a section for multiple PO's and units. So essentially each shipment can have one to many PO's and Units. Currently I can approach this task with the redundant method of reentering information per PO on the form. But I want to make this simple.

So the task at hand is that I want to have a form field for PO's and Units where I can input multiple lines of information so that when I hit a submit button. It appears in the database on separate lines with the same vendor information.

So if I filled out my form had this in the middle section:

```
PO         | Units
111111        22
222222        33
333333        44
```

When I hit submit I want it to attach the rest of the forms information to each PO on separate lines so it'd be like:

```
Vendor | City    | State |    PO    | Units
Nike     Memphis    TN     111111     22
Nike     Memphis    TN     222222     33
Nike     Memphis    TN     333333     44
```

So how would I go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem and your example of how the data appears to ultimately be stored in Access it looks to me like you are using Access as a spreadsheet and not as a database. This is ok, but you might want to consider normalizing the data to take advantage of the power of databases in general.

For example:

- Create a Vendors table whose sole purpose is to keep details about each Vendor you work with. A very basic implementation would have an `ID` field to uniquely identify each vendor and a `Name` field for the vendor name.
- If Vendors will only ever have a single location you *could* also store City, State, ZipCode and Email in this same Vendor table, but I suspect having a separate VendorLocation or VendorAddress table would be a better fit long term.
- Create a VendorShipment table that tracks the higher level information on your mockup, such as:

  - ShipmentID (primary key of this table)
  - VendorID (foreign key back to Vendor table)
  - Ready Date
  - Carrier
  - Estimated Cost
  - FreightClass
  - Tracking #
  - Estimated Transit Time
- Finally, create a VendorShipmentDetail table that tracks the information of each shipment, including:

  - ShipmentDetailID (primary key of this table)
  - ShipmentID (foreign key back to VendorShipment table)
  - PO
  - Units
  - Any other details that you want to or need to track

Organizing and storing the data in a normalized fashion would ultimately help simplify your data entry \ data management process and potentially make for a better user experience.

For example, rather than having to enter the Vendor Name, Address information, etc. each time you could instead use a combo box control that is tied to the `Vendor` table. If the Vendor exists in the table you select it from the list and you already have the Address information, no need to re-enter it each time. If the Vendor did not already exist you enter it once (probably on a Vendor screen where you maintain the details for each Vendor) and draw upon the information in the future.

You would then use queries to tie the information back together for reporting purposes (de-normalize the information).

The art of database design can take a while to pick up, but a good starting point might be to check out the Northwind database that Microsoft has maintained over the years. It has some examples you could draw from immediately to get a practical understanding of how to use normalization within Access. You can find more information here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/northwind-sales-web-database-TC101114818.aspx